# Let $d = \gcd(a,b)$. If $a = da'$ and $b = db'$, show that $\gcd(a',b')=1$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

> Let $d = \gcd(a,b)$. If $a = da'$ and $b = db'$, show that $\gcd(a',b')=1$.

So far I concluded that $d$ divides both $a$ and $b$, and their remainders are zero. I don't know what to do next, someone please help me. Thank you.

Comment: You mean $a=da'$, I think, instead of $a=d'a$. If gcd$(a',b') =c >1$, then $a'=ca'', b'=cb''$. So...?

Comment: Have you heard of [Bezout's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity)?

Comment: Thank you for the correction, and yes I have heard of Bezout's identity

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to continue is to do what is called a proof by contradiction which should look something like this:

1. Assume that $\gcd(a',b')\neq 1$
2. Do some math
3. Arrive at a nonsensical conclusion
4. From 3., you can conclude that $\gcd(a', b')=1$.

---

In your case, assume that $\gcd(a', b')=g\neq 1$. Then, define $a'' = \frac{a'}{g}$ and $b'' = \frac{b'}{g}$.

Now:

- Can you prove that $a''$ and $b''$ are integers?
- Can you show that $a'=ga''$ and $b'=gb''$?
- Can you now find a number that divides both $a$ and $b$ and is **larger** than $d$ (**Hint**: think about what $a$ is equal to if $a=da'$ and $a'=ga''$... and do the same with $b$).
- Can you now see a contradiction?

Answer (score 0):

If $gdc(a', b')$ was $d'>1$ then $dd'$ would divide both a and b. So d would not still be the Greatest Common divisor.